# Sending email to multiple cc recipients in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a function that sends an email like this:

```
Mail::to($email)
->cc($arraywithemails)
->send(new document());
```

How do I send the email to multiple cc users? I have checked the official documentation but there is no clue there.

Comment: You should just be able to use cc() or bcc(), they are in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The setAdress() function in Mailable allow you to give an array as argument:

[Mailable.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L567)

So You should be able to use the function by passing an array as your argument

```
Mail::to($email)
    ->cc(['name1@example.com','name2@example.com'])
    ->send(new document());
```

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L406 shows `@param  object|array|string  $address` in Laravel 5.5 for the `cc()` function. So it's acceptable to pass an object, array, or string. So go ahead and pass an array of the multiple strings you have as recipients.

Answer (score 12):

That should work. From the offical Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail):

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Comment: BCC and CC are totally different things.

Comment: They are totally different things. I don't understand the downvote. It was to show the OP the possibilities and that his code should work in any case as it does accept an array of values.

Comment: The solution to "I want to CC multiple people" simply isn't "use BCC for the second person".

Comment: It isn't. I provided a link to the official documentation as OP said he/she cannot find it. The answer is primarily to guide OP in the right direction as well but, that's okay :)

Comment: I think ceejayoz was saying that you could have clearly explained that the docs imply (and *also* do not clearly explain) that `cc()` and `bcc()` accept strings *or* arrays.